# Images not resizing in WYGWAM/Safecracker/Channel Images entry form

Tags: expressionengine

I have a blog that uses Channel Images to upload and manage images. The content area is a WYGWAM field. I have a few sizes set up in Channel Images to allow the user to adjust the layout inside their content (landscape left, landscape right, portrait left, portrait right) when adding images to the WYGWAM content field. I then have two other sizes: thumb and gallery. These are for the image gallery that appears below the content. Thumb is set as the small preview in the field settings, and gallery is set as the big preview in the field settings. It all works great in the CP publish form.

However, when using the Safecracker form things don't work as well. I can select existing images, but when I add a photo to the content field (WYGWAM) it does not resize it properly. I do get the dialog box and options I want to choose from, but that choice is not being saved.

What happens is the image is added to the WYGWAM content using the size I have selected in the field settings as the big preview. I tested this by changing what size is selected for "big preview".

However, if I upload a new image and select a size it works fine. The issue is only with existing images (ie uploaded previously for other entries).

Is it possible to use sizes in Channel Images/safecracker/wygwam?

Comment: BTW...if anyone can point me to documentation for Channel Images and Safecracker I would appreciate it. I don't see anything on devdemon's site.

Comment: Here is the [Channel Images documentation](http://www.devdemon.com/docs/channel_images/index.html), and here is the [Safecracker documentation](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/index.html) :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant docs for using Channel Images WITH Safecracker. I did look over both sets of docs and got it working, but wasn't sure if there were additional docs from DevDemon that I missed that had details about Safecracker and specifically this issue.

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors?

Comment: No errors. I will open a ticket with DD and see if this is something they've seen before.

Comment: I also found that things work fine with new uploads, it is only the stored uploads that are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the most recent build. The developer has sent me a patched version that is working.